# Storyboard doesn't animate if by default the control is disabled when it is loaded

Tags: xaml, storyboard, windows-store-apps, disabled-control

I have an issue in animating the storyboard when the control loads for the first time. Once it is loaded then if i change its IsEnabled to true or false then it works. I wonder if that is how it works. But the same funda works just fine in Windows phone app.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SyncBtnStyle}" Tag="/Assets/topicon_refresh.png" 
                IsEnabled="False" />


        <Style x:Key="SyncBtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BgEllipse">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainImg" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0">
                            <Grid>
                                <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Margin="4 6 4 4" Opacity="0" x:Name="BgEllipse"/>
                                <Image x:Name="MainImg" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform/>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Help me if i'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. As it sits if the Button IsEnabled=False then it will go into the Disabled VisualState where apparently you just keep spinning it around while it's in that state? I mean seems like an odd user experience but who am I to say.

Comment: @ChrisW. It could just be for testing purposes. @Srini you could add a `Loaded` event which toggles the `IsEnabled`. Or you could try adding a `VisualTransition`.

Comment: @Chris For others understanding i made it like if it is Disabled it should perform the action but the logic behind is to spin the Sync image(Button) when the IsSync(bool) variable is true. So when it syncs i want to disable the sync button so that user will not click it again. Here i'll inverse the IsSync value to bind it to IsEnabled property. Is it Clear now?

Comment: @Nate Diamond I dont want to raise loaded event. I bind the value like this IsEnabled="{Binding IsSync, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolean}}" i dont want to add any code to codebehind. IsSync comes from baseviewmodel, so the value will be set somewhere accordingly this button should react. It works fine with Windows phone.

Comment: I wonder if it possibly does not have a `CompositeTransform` by default. Try manually adding a `Transform` (and possibly naming it), then targeting that.